# Chart for Fame/Infamy for Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

When first gaining a level of Fame and Infamy in Fallout New Vegas the game gave you a chart of what every title meant. I accidentally quickly exited out of this and I can't find its image anywhere online and any wiki I came across wasn't helpful. I was wondering if anybody could provide an image of the chart of levels of Fame/Infamy or make one themselves so I know how much each faction either loves me or hates me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find such a [chart on Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_reputations#Reputation), which is an excellent reference to check before asking a question about Fallout on Arqade.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just wanting to confirm to make sure I have it right, "Vilified" is the worst Infamy status you can have, right?

Comment: @Bucky That's right. Idolized is the best.